# ddclient: Invalid Value for keyword 'ip' = '' (Dynamic DNS)

Tags: dns, ddclient

Previous posts on this topic appear to be outdated or not useful. Running 17.04 on a Pine64.

When running ddclient with dynu.com service I get an email with the following error (*** where I deleted values for privacy):

```
WARNING:  file /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache, line 8: Invalid Value for keyword 'ip' = ''
WARNING:  skipping update of ***.DYNU.NET from <nothing> to ***.
WARNING:   last updated <never> but last attempt on Tue Jun 20 15:26:07 2017 failed.
WARNING:   Wait at least 5 minutes between update attempts.
```

My configuration file looks like this:

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf
daemon=150
syslog=yes
mail=***
mail-failure=***
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid
ssl=yes

use=web, web=checkip.dynu.com/, web-skip='IP Address'
server=api.dynu.com
protocol=dyndns2
server=dynu.com
login=***
password='***
***.DYNU.NET
```

I've tried different IP services as well, such as ipinfo.io/ip

Any new patches or updates on this issue?

Comment: You have `server` defined twice, and domain set at ***.DYNU.NET instead of ***.dynu.net.

Comment: So when I adjust for those issues I get the following messages:

'WARNING:  file /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache, line 9: Invalid Value for keyword 'ip' = ''
WARNING:  updating saxafray.dynu.net: nochg: No update required; unnecessary attempts to change to the
current address are considered abusive

Comment: Delete `/var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache`. The WARNING message is because you're trying to update to many times in too short of a period.

Comment: Also, try and change web-skip to 'Current IP Address: ' and note the space after the :

Answer (score 5):

So, I changed the web domain to: ipinfo.io/ip

And removed the second instance of `server`.

My final config file looks like this:

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf
daemon=150
syslog=yes
mail=***
mail-failure=***
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid
ssl=yes

use=web, web=ipinfo.io/ip
server=api.dynu.com
protocol=dyndns2
#server=dynu.com
login=***
password='***'
***.DYNU.NET
```

And I got the wonderful email:

```
SUCCESS:  updating ***.DYNU.NET: good: IP address set to ***
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on logs, the solution was installing "libio-socket-ssl-perl" package in my case using OSMC.

```
On Debian, the package libio-socket-ssl-perl must be installed.
On Red Hat, the package perl-IO-Socket-SSL must be installed.
On Alpine, the package perl-io-socket-ssl must be installed.
```